# Use the sitemap content element to load content of the referenced pages

Tags: typo3, sitemap

I use the sitemap content element so that the editor can explicitly reference to individual pages in my page tree. Of course those pages do contain content elements (Textpic, Media, all the good stuff...) in their "normal" section. I need advice on how to modify the sitemap content element that it will output the content of the referenced pages.

I know there is already a plugin called "kb_sitemap" which basicaley does this job... but it does not handle the output of images or media (flash-, quicktime movies..) elements which is absolute necessary. The rendering relevant stuff is handled by Css Styled Content (CSC) which is necassary for me because it renders the media content element.

Comment: Wouldn't simple references to existing pages be a solution? Like using page properties -> appearance tab -> replace content...

Comment: I did not knew that this excists. Unfortunately it can only reference to one other side. I need to reference to as much sites as I want.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use `templavoila` ? 
Ok, go to page properties -> General tab (bottom part of the tab) and then you'll find all containers that possibly contain CEs, click to the lil folder icon and you may select content elements from any other page.

EDIT: added screenshot, page properties... [image]
Note, showcase, maincontent, right content are just my names for my TV elements, could of course be name differently.